# Custom php in rules how to check users' geolocation lat lon field and return only users in certain area

Tags: location

I have some custom php, sending privatemsgs to users who have some term_reference field terms that match node term_reference field terms. I need to add into this so that it only contacts users who are within a certain range of area based on their lat lon that they entered on sign up. I am sure this is a very common thing to do e.g. showing users nearby etc. If you can point me in the right direction, would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using javascript? You could submit it with ajax and write it to the db.

Here is a good example of a javascript geolocation function to get long and altitude:

```
window.onload = function(){
    if(navigator.geolocation)
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(handleGetCurrentPosition, onError);
}

function handleGetCurrentPosition(location){

    location.coords.latitude;
    location.coords.longitude;
}
function onError(){...}
```

More complete demo:
http://od-eon.com/labs/geolocation/

For the calculation of the distance with php:
http://www.dzone.com/snippets/distance-calculation-using-1